# endpoints-proto-datastore can't get rid of defaults filter

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

I have an `EndpointsModel` named "File" with some fields:

```
path = ndb.StringProperty()
filedata = ndb.TextProperty()
check = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=False)
of = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=False)
created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
updated = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

I'm using endpoints-proto-datastore query method:

```
@NativFile.query_method(query_fields=('limit', 'order', 'pageToken',
    'created', 'check', 'of'),
    path='files/all', name='query')
def NativFileList(self, query):
    print query # For Debug
    return query
```

I am sending a GET request to the endpoint with no parameters (only limit=10). But when the app prints the query I can see there is a filter for `of` and `check` with their default values `false`.

How can I get rid of this default filters?

Answer (score 0):

To override the default filter, set your own. If you want to not filter, try making your filter overly general.